# How to convert simple pandas dataframe to multi-index/column dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following data frame

| AAPL | INCOME STATEMENT (in mln.) | Revenue | COGS | Gross Profit | Gross Profit ratio | Research and Development Exp. | General and Administrative Exp. | Selling and Marketing Exp. | Selling, General and Administrative Exp. | Other Expenses | Operating Expenses | COGS and Expenses | Interest Expenese | Depreciation and Amortization | EBITDA | EBITDA ratio | Operating Income | Operating Income ratio | Total Other Income Expenses Net | Income Before Tax | Income Before Tax ratio | Income Tax expense | Net Income | Net Income ratio | EPS | EPS Diluted | Weighted Average Shares Outstanding | Weighted Average Shares Outstanding Diluted | BALANCE SHEET (in mln.) | Cash and Cash Equivalents | Short-Term Investments | Cash and Short-Term Investments | Net Receivables | Inventory | Other Current Assets | Total Current Assets | PP&E | Goodwill | Intangible Assets | Goodwill and Intangible Assets | Investments | Tax Assets | Other Non-Current Assets | Total Non-Current Assets | Other Assets | Total Assets | Accounts Payable | Short-Term Debt | Tax Payable | Deferred Revenue | Other Current Liabilities | Total Current Liabilities | Long-Term Debt | Deferred Revenue | Deferred Tax Liabilities | Other Non-Current Liabilities | Total Non-Current Liabilities | Other Liabilities | Total Liabilities | Common Stock | Retained Earnings | Other Comprehensive Income/Loss | Other Total Stockholders Equity | Total Stockholders Equity | Total Liabilities And Stockholders Equity | CASH FLOW STATEMENT (in mln.) | Net Income | Depreciation and Amortization | Deferred Income Tax | Stock Based Compensation | Change in Working Capital | Accounts Receivable | Inventory | Accounts Payable | Other Working Capital | Other Non-Cash Items | Cash Provided by Operating Activities | CAPEX | Acquisitions Net | Purchases of Investments | Sales/Maturities of Investments | Other Investing Activites | Cash Used for Investing Activites | Debt Repayment | Common Stock Issued | Common Stock Repurchased | Dividends Paid | Other Financing Activites | Cash Used/Provided by Financing Activities | Effect of Forex Changes on Cash | Net Change In Cash | Cash at the Beginning of Period | Cash at the End of Period | Free Cash Flow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 |  | 274,515 | 169,559 | 104,956 | 38.23% | 18,752 | - - | - - | 19,916 | - - | 38,668 | 208,227 | 2,873 | 11,056 | 81,020 | 29.51% | 66,288 | 24.15% | 803 | 67,091 | 24.44% | 9,680 | 57,411 | 20.91% | 3.31 | 3.28 | 17,352 | 17,528 |  | 38,016 | 52,927 | 90,943 | 37,445 | 4,061 | 11,264 | 143,713 | 36,766 | - - | - - | - - | 100,887 | - - | 42,522 | 180,175 | - - | 323,888 | 42,296 | 13,769 | - - | 6,643 | 42,684 | 105,392 | 98,667 | - - | - - | 54,490 | 153,157 | - - | 258,549 | 50,779 | 14,966 | (406) | - - | 65,339 | 323,888 |  | 57,411 | 11,056 | (215) | 6,829 | 5,690 | 6,917 | (127) | (4,062) | 2,081 | (97) | 80,674 | (7,309) | (1,524) | (115,148) | 120,483 | (791) | (4,289) | (12,629) | 880 | (72,358) | (14,081) | 11,368 | (86,820) | - - | (10,435) | 50,224 | 39,789 | 73,365 |
| 2021 |  | 365,817 | 212,981 | 152,836 | 41.78% | 21,914 | - - | - - | 21,973 | - - | 43,887 | 256,868 | 2,645 | 11,284 | 123,136 | 33.66% | 108,949 | 29.78% | 258 | 109,207 | 29.85% | 14,527 | 94,680 | 25.88% | 5.67 | 5.61 | 16,701 | 16,865 |  | 34,940 | 27,699 | 62,639 | 51,506 | 6,580 | 14,111 | 134,836 | 39,440 | - - | - - | - - | 127,877 | - - | 48,849 | 216,166 | - - | 351,002 | 54,763 | 15,613 | - - | 7,612 | 47,493 | 125,481 | 109,106 | - - | - - | 53,325 | 162,431 | - - | 287,912 | 57,365 | 5,562 | 163 | - - | 63,090 | 351,002 |  | 94,680 | 11,284 | (4,774) | 7,906 | (4,911) | (10,125) | (2,642) | 12,326 | 1,676 | (147) | 104,038 | (11,085) | (33) | (109,689) | 106,870 | (608) | (14,545) | (8,750) | 1,105 | (85,971) | (14,467) | 14,730 | (93,353) | - - | (3,860) | 39,789 | 35,929 | 92,953 |

Now I want to have this dataframe with multi-columns. Something similar to given below. The columns "Revenue" to "Total Liabilities And Stockholders Equity" should fall under "income statement" and so on. I couldn't wrap my head around to make it work using the documentation given [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html). Your help will be highly appreciated.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | INCOME STATEMENT (in mln.) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | BALANCE SHEET (in mln.) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | CASH FLOW STATEMENT (in mln.) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | Revenue | COGS | Gross Profit | Gross Profit ratio | Research and Development Exp. | General and Administrative Exp. | Selling and Marketing Exp. | Selling, General and Administrative Exp. | Other Expenses | Operating Expenses | COGS and Expenses | Interest Expenese | Depreciation and Amortization | EBITDA | EBITDA ratio | Operating Income | Operating Income ratio | Total Other Income Expenses Net | Income Before Tax | Income Before Tax ratio | Income Tax expense | Net Income | Net Income ratio | EPS | EPS Diluted | Weighted Average Shares Outstanding | Weighted Average Shares Outstanding Diluted | Cash and Cash Equivalents | Short-Term Investments | Cash and Short-Term Investments | Net Receivables | Inventory | Other Current Assets | Total Current Assets | PP&E | Goodwill | Intangible Assets | Goodwill and Intangible Assets | Investments | Tax Assets | Other Non-Current Assets | Total Non-Current Assets | Other Assets | Total Assets | Accounts Payable | Short-Term Debt | Tax Payable | Deferred Revenue | Other Current Liabilities | Total Current Liabilities | Long-Term Debt | Deferred Revenue | Deferred Tax Liabilities | Other Non-Current Liabilities | Total Non-Current Liabilities | Other Liabilities | Total Liabilities | Common Stock | Retained Earnings | Other Comprehensive Income/Loss | Other Total Stockholders Equity | Total Stockholders Equity | Total Liabilities And Stockholders Equity | Net Income | Depreciation and Amortization | Deferred Income Tax | Stock Based Compensation | Change in Working Capital | Accounts Receivable | Inventory | Accounts Payable | Other Working Capital | Other Non-Cash Items | Cash Provided by Operating Activities | CAPEX | Acquisitions Net | Purchases of Investments | Sales/Maturities of Investments | Other Investing Activites | Cash Used for Investing Activites | Debt Repayment | Common Stock Issued | Common Stock Repurchased | Other Financing Activites | Effect of Forex Changes on Cash | Cash at the Beginning of Period | Free Cash Flow |
| 2020 | 274,515 | 169,559 | 104,956 | 38.23% | 18,752 | - - | - - | 19,916 | - - | 38,668 | 208,227 | 2,873 | 11,056 | 81,020 | 29.51% | 66,288 | 24.15% | 803 | 67,091 | 24.44% | 9,680 | 57,411 | 20.91% | 3.31 | 3.28 | 17,352 | 17,528 | 38,016 | 52,927 | 90,943 | 37,445 | 4,061 | 11,264 | 143,713 | 36,766 | - - | - - | - - | 100,887 | - - | 42,522 | 180,175 | - - | 323,888 | 42,296 | 13,769 | - - | 6,643 | 42,684 | 105,392 | 98,667 | - - | - - | 54,490 | 153,157 | - - | 258,549 | 50,779 | 14,966 | (406) | - - | 65,339 | 323,888 | 57,411 | 11,056 | (215) | 6,829 | 5,690 | 6,917 | (127) | (4,062) | 2,081 | (97) | 80,674 | (7,309) | (1,524) | (115,148) | 120,483 | (791) | (4,289) | (12,629) | 880 | (72,358) | 11,368 | - - | 50,224 | 73,365 |
| 2021 | 365,817 | 212,981 | 152,836 | 41.78% | 21,914 | - - | - - | 21,973 | - - | 43,887 | 256,868 | 2,645 | 11,284 | 123,136 | 33.66% | 108,949 | 29.78% | 258 | 109,207 | 29.85% | 14,527 | 94,680 | 25.88% | 5.67 | 5.61 | 16,701 | 16,865 | 34,940 | 27,699 | 62,639 | 51,506 | 6,580 | 14,111 | 134,836 | 39,440 | - - | - - | - - | 127,877 | - - | 48,849 | 216,166 | - - | 351,002 | 54,763 | 15,613 | - - | 7,612 | 47,493 | 125,481 | 109,106 | - - | - - | 53,325 | 162,431 | - - | 287,912 | 57,365 | 5,562 | 163 | - - | 63,090 | 351,002 | 94,680 | 11,284 | (4,774) | 7,906 | (4,911) | (10,125) | (2,642) | 12,326 | 1,676 | (147) | 104,038 | (11,085) | (33) | (109,689) | 106,870 | (608) | (14,545) | (8,750) | 1,105 | (85,971) | 14,730 | - - | 39,789 | 92,953 |

Answer (score 1):

With the following toy dataframe mimicking yours:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Status": [2020, 2021],
        "INCOME STATEMENT": ["", ""],
        "Revenue": [274515, 212981],
        "Operating Expenses": [38668, 43887],
        "COGS": [208227, 256868],
        "Cash": [38016, 34940],
        "BALANCE SHEET": ["", ""],
        "Inventory": [4061, 6580],
        "Investments": [100887, 127887],
    }
)

print(df)
# Output
   Status INCOME STATEMENT  Revenue  Operating Expenses    COGS   Cash  \
0    2020                    274515               38668  208227  38016   
1    2021                    212981               43887  256868  34940   

  BALANCE SHEET  Inventory  Investments  
0                     4061       100887  
1                     6580       127887
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Define levels for multiIndex dataframe
COL_LVL_0 = ["", "INCOME STATEMENT", "BALANCE SHEET"]
STARTING_COLS = ["Status", "COGS", "Inventory"]

# Remove empty columns
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(COL_LVL_0)]

# Slice dataframe columns list to get level 1 labels for each level 0 label
indices = [df.columns.tolist().index(value) for value in STARTING_COLS]
cols_lvl_1 = []
for idx in indices:
    if idx == 0:
        start = 0
        continue
    cols_lvl_1.append(df.columns.tolist()[start:idx])
    start = idx
cols_lvl_1.append(df.columns.tolist()[start:])

# Setup new index
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    ((lvl0, lvl1) for lvl0, item in zip(COL_LVL_0, cols_lvl_1) for lvl1 in item)
)
```

So that:

```py
print(df)
# Output
                                    INCOME STATEMENT        BALANCE SHEET  \
  Status Revenue Operating Expenses             COGS   Cash     Inventory   
0   2020  274515              38668           208227  38016          4061   
1   2021  212981              43887           256868  34940          6580   


  Investments  
0      100887  
1      127887
```